# How to add user authentication to botframework app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

Trying to build a recipe ordering app via SMS using Bot Framework. How can I let the user 'login' to view all his previous recipes?

The user first must sign up through a website using Azure Active Directory B2C. I got the API sample template up and running and it lets me authenticate user through the website...

But I'm not sure how to authenticate this logged in user (on the website) on the bot chat level. How can I make Bot Framework be aware of this logged in user?

It'd be really nice if you could just turn on multi-factor authentication and access the phone number connected to the user but this is not possible programmatically at the moment according to Microsoft.

Any other ideas? I desperately need some way to allow a mobile phone user to authenticate via SMS and access their private data through it. I tried it with Active Directory's .net api sample but no documentation exists on how to make this all work together with Bot Framework...

Answer (score 0):

I ran the pizza bot template and pondered upon the same question.

I ended up taking the user ID and store it along with any information I could get through claims. Then, I a reference for the user that I can look up and do stuff with. Not sure if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

1. Generate an authentication URL and send it to your user via the bot. Ask him to login to the service using the URL.
2. The server would receive the result of that authentication (your API for the bot is now aware of the result) and if successful, you can show the data to the user through the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look to the [Facebook Auth sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot) to get an idea of a potential flow for the Auth scenario.

Hope this helps.